# How do I access a property of the “response” of an API call from my Angular operation?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an API made in NODE.JS that brings an object as its response, an image of which I have posted below.

[image: {recordsets: Array(1), recordset: Array(70), output: {…}, rowsAffected: Array(1)}]

Here is my typescript code that I have in my users.component.ts file.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent {
  users: any[];
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('url').subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.recordset);
      this.users=response.recordset;
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the error message that I receive:

> src/app/users/users.component.ts:14:28 - error TS2339: Property 'recordset' does not exist on type 'Object’.
>
> 14       console.log(response.recordset);
>
> src/app/users/users.component.ts:15:27 - error TS2339: Property 'recordset' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>
> 15       this.users=response.recordset;

How do I access this “recordset” property and add it into the users array?

Comment: Try `http.get<any>(url).subscribe(response => {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know the response type of the returned response, you can avoid the error by adding **`any`** which will fix the issue for you.

However best practice would be having the type of the response,

```
  http.get('url').subscribe((response : any) => {
```